# Jetspeed 2 with Tomcat 6 on Windows 7 does not forward after logon

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, tomcat6

I have a Jetspeed 2 portal instance that runs on Tomcat 6.0.29 in a Windows 7 machine (used to work on XP). The portal login succeeds but it does not forward to the logged in view. Has anyone encountered this issue? If yes, do you have a fix/ workaround for it

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverted to Tomcat 6.0.18 and everything is working.